# dispatch change event on select tag that has dynamic selection

Tags: javascript, events

I want to dispatch the event so I can run the function inside the eventlistener

I've tried:

```
var event = new Event('change'); 
i.dispatchEvent(event);
```

but it didn't work without giving any error

```js
let i = document.querySelector('#i');

i.querySelector('[value="7"]').selected = true;

//dispatch event
let ev = new Event("change");
i.dispatchEvent(ev); 

i.addEventListener('change', e=>{
  alert('selected : '+e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<select id="i">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dispatching the event before you add event listener, that's why it's not working. You need to add event listener first, then dispatch the event:

```css
let i = document.querySelector('#i');

i.querySelector('[value="7"]').selected = true;

// Add event listener first
i.addEventListener('change', e=>{
  alert('selected : ' + e.target.value);
});


// Dispatch event after event listener is added
let ev = new Event("change");
i.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

```html
<select id="i">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```